# Typescript: can not access member value in inherited class constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop, inheritance, ecmascript-6

I have a class `A`, and a class `B` inherited from it.

```
class A {
    constructor(){
        this.init();
    }
    init(){}
}

class B extends A {
    private myMember = {value:1};
    constructor(){
        super();
    }
    init(){
        console.log(this.myMember.value);
    }
}

const x = new B();
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
```

How can I avoid this error?

It's clear for me that the JavaScript code will call the `init` method before it creates the `myMember`, but there should be some practice/pattern to make it work.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is why in some languages (cough C#) code analysis tools flag usage of virtual members inside constructors.

In Typescript field initializations happen in the constructor, after the call to the base constructor. The fact that field initializations are written near the field is just syntactic sugar. If we look at the generated code the problem becomes clear:

```
function B() {
    var _this = _super.call(this) || this; // base call here, field has not been set, init will be called
    _this.myMember = { value: 1 }; // field init here
    return _this;
}
```

You should consider a solution where init is either called from outside the instance, and not in the constructor:

```
class A {
    constructor(){
    }
    init(){}
}

class B extends A {
    private myMember = {value:1};
    constructor(){
        super();
    }
    init(){
        console.log(this.myMember.value);
    }
}

const x = new B();
x.init();
```

Or you can have an extra parameter to your constructor that specifies whether to call `init` and not call it in the derived class as well.

```
class A {
    constructor()
    constructor(doInit: boolean)
    constructor(doInit?: boolean){
        if(doInit || true)this.init();
    }
    init(){}
}

class B extends A {
    private myMember = {value:1};
    constructor()
    constructor(doInit: boolean)
    constructor(doInit?: boolean){
        super(false);
        if(doInit || true)this.init();
    }
    init(){
        console.log(this.myMember.value);
    }
}

const x = new B();
```

Or the very very very dirty solution of `setTimeout`, which will defer initialization until the current frame completes. This will let the parent constructor call to complete, but there will be an interim between constructor call and when the timeout expires when the object has not been `init`ed

```
class A {
    constructor(){
        setTimeout(()=> this.init(), 1);
    }
    init(){}
}

class B extends A {
    private myMember = {value:1};
    constructor(){
        super();
    }
    init(){
        console.log(this.myMember.value);
    }
}

const x = new B();
// x is not yet inited ! but will be soon
```

Answer (score 7):

Because `myMember` property is accessed in parent constructor (`init()` is called during `super()` call), there is no way how it can be defined in child constructor without hitting a race condition.

There are several alternative approaches.

## `init` hook

`init` is considered a hook that shouldn't be called in class constructor. Instead, it is called explicitly:

```
new B();
B.init();
```

Or it is called implicitly by the framework, as a part of application lifecycle.

## Static property

If a property is supposed to be a constant, it can be static property.

This is the most efficient way because this is what static members are for, but the syntax may be not that attractive because it requires to use `this.constructor` instead of class name if static property should be properly referred in child classes:

```
class B extends A {
    static readonly myMember = { value: 1 };

    init() {
        console.log((this.constructor as typeof B).myMember.value);
    }
}
```

## Property getter/setter

Property descriptor can be defined on class prototype with `get`/`set` syntax. If a property is supposed to be primitive constant, it can be just a getter:

```
class B extends A {
    get myMember() {
        return 1;
    }

    init() {
        console.log(this.myMember);
    }
}
```

It becomes more hacky if the property is not constant or primitive:

```
class B extends A {
    private _myMember?: { value: number };

    get myMember() {
        if (!('_myMember' in this)) {
            this._myMember = { value: 1 }; 
        }

        return this._myMember!;
    }
    set myMember(v) {
        this._myMember = v;
    }

    init() {
        console.log(this.myMember.value);
    }
}
```

## In-place initialization

A property may be initialized where it's accessed first. If this happens in `init` method where `this` can be accessed prior to `B` class constructor, this should happen there:

```
class B extends A {
    private myMember?: { value: number };

    init() {
        this.myMember = { value: 1 }; 
        console.log(this.myMember.value);
    }
}
```

## Asynchronous initialization

`init` method may become asynchronous. Initialization state should be trackable, so the class should implement some API for that, e.g. promise-based:

```
class A {
    initialization = Promise.resolve();
    constructor(){
        this.init();
    }
    init(){}
}

class B extends A {
    private myMember = {value:1};

    init(){
        this.initialization = this.initialization.then(() => {
            console.log(this.myMember.value);
        });
    }
}

const x = new B();
x.initialization.then(() => {
    // class is initialized
})
```

This approach may be considered antipattern for this particular case because initialization routine is intrinsically synchronous, but it may be suitable for asynchronous initialization routines.

## Desugared class

Since ES6 classes have limitations on the use of `this` prior to `super`, child class can be desugared to a function to evade this limitation:

```
interface B extends A {}
interface BPrivate extends B {
    myMember: { value: number };
}
interface BStatic extends A {
    new(): B;
}
const B = <BStatic><Function>function B(this: BPrivate) {
    this.myMember = { value: 1 };
    return A.call(this); 
}

B.prototype.init = function () {
    console.log(this.myMember.value);
}
```

This is rarely a good option, because desugared class should be additionally typed in TypeScript. This also won't work with native parent classes (TypeScript `es6` and `esnext` target).

Answer (score 3):

One approach you could take is use a getter/setter for **myMember** and manage the default value in the getter. This would prevent the undefined problem and allow you to keep almost exactly the same structure you have. Like this:

```
class A {
    constructor(){
        this.init();
    }
    init(){}
}

class B extends A {
    private _myMember;
    constructor(){
        super();
    }
    init(){
        console.log(this.myMember.value);
    }

    get myMember() {
        return this._myMember || { value: 1 };
    }

    set myMember(val) {
        this._myMember = val;
    }
}

const x = new B();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
class A {
    constructor() {
        this.init();
    }
    init() { }
}

class B extends A {
    private myMember = { 'value': 1 };
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    init() {
        this.myMember = { 'value': 1 };
        console.log(this.myMember.value);
    }
}

const x = new B();
```

Comment: Yep, but in this case I have to redeclare `myMember` which I would no like to do.

Answer (score 2):

Super has to be first command. Remeber that typescript is more "javascript with documentation of types" rather than language on its own.

If you look to the transpiled code .js it is clearly visible:

```
class A {
    constructor() {
        this.init();
    }
    init() {
    }
}
class B extends A {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.myMember = { value: 1 };
    }
    init() {
        console.log(this.myMember.value);
    }
}
const x = new B();
```

Comment: It does the same. `init()` will be called before `this.myMember` is declared.

Comment: @Adam - read the answer once more, I have posted the .js file that was created by typescript.

Comment: ok, thats right, sorry. but it is not a solution for my problem :-/

Comment: @Adam - there is no solution, you cannot use it like this

Answer (score 2):

Do you have to call init in class A?

That works fine, but I don't know if you have different requirements:

```
class A {
  constructor(){}
  init(){}
}

class B extends A {
  private myMember = {value:1};
  constructor(){
      super();
      this.init();
  }
  init(){
      console.log(this.myMember.value);
  }
}

const x = new B();
```

Answer (score 0):

More often than not, you can defer the call of `init()` to a time just before it is needed by hacking into one of your getters.

For example:

```
class FoodieParent {
  public init() {
    favoriteFood = "Salad";
  }

  public _favoriteFood: string;
  public set favoriteFood(val) { this._favoriteFood = val; }
  public get favoriteFood() {
    if (!this._favoriteFood) {
      this.init();
    }
    return this._favoriteFood;
  }

  public talkAboutFood() {
    // init function automatically gets called just in time, because "favoriteFood" is a getter
    console.log(`I love ${this.favoriteFood}`);
  }
}

// overloading the init function works without having to call `init()` afterwards
class FoodieChild extends FoodieParent {
  public init() {
    this.favoriteFood = "Pizza"
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Like this :

```
 class A
{
     myMember; 
    constructor() {

    }

    show() {
        alert(this.myMember.value);
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public myMember = {value:1};

    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}

const test = new B;
test.show();
```