# Typescript - call abstract method from abstract constructor or provide equivalent functionality

Tags: typescript, constructor, abstract-class, abstract

<s>In Typescript - abstract methods cannot be called from within abstract constructors (the code will compile, but will crash at runtime).</s>

Take the following example where the code crashes:

```
abstract class Puzzle {


    addState = () => {
         let data = this.createStateData()
         //Perform a operation with data 
    }

    abstract createStateData: () => Object

    protected constructor() {
        //The code crashes here because createStateData
        //has not been defined yet
        this.addState()
     }

}

class RiverPuzzle extends Puzzle {

    createStateData = (): Object => {
         return 'Foo'
    }

    constructor() { 
        super()
        //this.addState()
    }

}
```

In this particular example, the problem can be solved by uncommenting the line in the constructor of the `RiverPuzzle` class and commenting the offending line in the constructor of the abstract class.

However, the solution is suboptimal because there are many classes extending the abstract class `Puzzle` and I don't want to manually add `this.addState()` to the constructor of every single subclass.

What is a more efficient alternative?

Comment: Add a data argument to the base class constructor, and pass it from the subclass constructor: `super('Foo')`

Comment: You're putting the methods on the instance, not the prototype.  Why?

Comment: Also calling abstract or overridden  methods in the constructor generally leads to unintuitive behavior: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775508/typescript-can-not-access-member-value-in-inherited-class-constructor

Comment: @jcalz If I understand your question correctly, the reason `createStateData` is not in the abstract class is because this example is simplified, in reality, `createStateData` is actually something like `return new RiverStateData(this.boat, this.passengers)` and the class `RiverPuzzle` would have the properties `boat` and `passengers`.

Comment: @Roymunson I thing he rather asks why you don't use *methods*: `createStateData() {
  return 'Foo';
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using [arrow functions as methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Arrow_functions_used_as_methods), which is generally discouraged.  It does weird things with `this`, and each instance of your class will have its own method as opposed to having just one method on the prototype.  Unless you have some good reason, I suggest you use prototype methods (not using arrow function notation), like this:

```
abstract class Puzzle {
    addState() {
         let data = this.createStateData()
         //Perform a operation with data 
    }

    abstract createStateData(): Object

    protected constructor() {
        this.addState()
     }
}

class RiverPuzzle extends Puzzle {
    createStateData() {
         return 'Foo'
    }

    constructor() { 
        super()            
    }
}
```

That should hopefully work more as you expect.

Comment: Update: The code still broke (but to a lesser degree), but that's just because `createStateData` was using `this` inside of it. Let this be a lesson to all future visitors - don't use abstract functions (at least ones that contain `this`) inside of abstract constructors.

Comment: There's absolutely no reason you shouldn't use `this` in abstract method implementations. @Roymunson the reason why your code is not working is something else, not reflected in this bare bones example.